# How to overlay two mix-blend-mode overlays

Tags: css

I am trying to create RGB channel overlays from grayscale images in CSS.

e.g.

Image1 -> Background
Image2 -> Grayscale image where all non-black pixels should be red (and black = transparent)
Image3 -> Grayscale image where all non-black pixels should be blue (and black = transparent)

```css
#background-img {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Gray_scale.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#foreground-img {
  background-image: url("https://blogs.mathworks.com/images/steve/166/labeled_regions_grayscale_01.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.square {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
}

.overlay {
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}

.overlay2 {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#red {
  background: red;
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="background-img" class="square"></div>
  <div id="red" class="square overlay">
    <div id="foreground-img" class="square overlay2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="blue" class="square overlay">
    <div id="foreground-img" class="square overlay2 "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works for one overlay (e.g. red), but as soon as I add the blue div the red div is no longer visible.

Comment: I didnt understand you want these 2 bg in one div?

Comment: Try using `.overlay { mix-blend-mode: color-dodge; }`.